# python column dataframe(strings) convert to lists of lists

Tags: python

i have a dataframe with rows of str. i selected a column and i want to convert it to lists of list.

tokens

```
[wXvP3enu, wXvHXzUS, wXvPHXVe, wXvPHRs3, wXvH3kX4, wXvPHMpZ, wXvHX3oR, wXv_kemV]    
[wXujANbk, wXurAJsf, wXufwlh1, wXtr_4tD, wXujgvJA, wXuTQ-mP, wXuTA-zh, wXuPAEDJ]    
[wXvHbNqU, wXvDrof9, wXv_aXHk, wXvDrSIa, wXv_apaj, wXv_aM0Q, wXv7aWTK, wXv3aQrM]        
[wXvb7cpv, wXvH3hL0, wXvjmDaE, wXvT0sOS, wXv_jgB_, wXMD-zp5, wXvLUyAh, wXvXQ3Fg]
```

tokens is a column of my dataframe and the infomation in it, is string. i want to convert these lists of strings to lists of list.

I tried it but it didn't work. I tried `json` too, but it didn't work!!!

```
token_load = load_df.loc[ : , "tokens"]

token_list = list()

for i in range(len(token_load)):

    token_list[i] =ast.literal_eval(token_load[i])
```

Comment: What's not working? And what errors are you getting?

Comment: raise ValueError(f'malformed node or string: {node!r}')
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x00000220196E2160>

Comment: It might be because the tokens you have are not in string format. Like instead of `'wXvP3enu'` you have `wXvP3enu` (without the `'`)

Comment: i checked the type and its str. and yes, they have not ( ' )

Comment: In order for `ast.literal_eval` to work it should look like `['wXvP3enu', 'wXvHXzUS', 'wXvPHX', ...]` and not `[wXvP3enu, wXvHXzUS, wXvPHX, ...]`

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: A quick and dirty way would be remove the square brackets, and split the string with `,`

Comment: can you tell me the code pls

Comment: Try something like `token_load[i].replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace(' ', '').split(',')`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `list.append`:

```
token_load = load_df.loc[ : , "tokens"]

token_list = list()

for i in range(len(token_load)):

    token_list.append(ast.literal_eval(token_load[i]))
```